# How can one set the color for the code in a package documentation?

Tags: color, ltxdockit

I am creating a LaTeX package. I would like to set the code in the PDF documentation of the package to purple instead of the usual black.
Could some one tell me how I could set the code color?

Comment: What package are you using to set the code?

Comment: Thanks @Werner for your prompt response. I am developing the package code in a ".dtx" file using the package "ltxdoc".

Comment: @user24098, `ltxdoc` is a class file, not a package. I think what Werner meant is which package are you using *to typeset the code*. Like `listings`, `minted`, or just the good ol' `verbatim` mode. `:)`

Comment: Thanks Guilherme Z. Santos. Sorry for the  **slip**: I meant to write `class ltxdoc` _not_ `package ltxdoc`. Yes I am using the good old verbatim mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest is this:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{macrocode}{\color{red}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Piet van Oostrum for a simple and elegant solution. It works perfectly for me. Cheers!